# Preserve datatype name when converting to JSON with ConvertTo-Json

Tags: json, powershell, ssis

I'm trying to export my SSIS catalog environment to a JSON file (with PowerShell). When I select the right columns I see "String" and "Int16" as value for the Type:
[image]
but when I convert to JSON with [ConvertTo-Json](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) it shows the int values instead of the string values:
[image]
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Please post code / textual output, rather than screenshots. Where does `$Environment` come from?

Comment: It comes from the SQL Server Integration Services catalog. Posting the entire code seems useless if you don't have SSIS. However your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: And here is my complete code if someone want to copy it: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2017/05/import-and-export-ssis-catalog.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the `Type` values are of type `[System.Data.DbType]`. `ConvertTo-Json` converts the value names to the underlying numerical value of the `DbType` enum.

You can override this behavior with the `Select-Object` statement:

```
$Environment.Variables |Select-Object Name,Description,@{Name='Type';Expression={"$($_.Type)"}},Sensitivity,Value |ConvertTo-Json
```